# Cannot use Gatsby Link with justify-content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I have a nav component using Gatsby Link along with styled components

**Original Nav component**

```
import React from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"
import { Link } from "gatsby"

const NavWrapper = styled.nav`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  @media screen and (max-width: 769px) {
    display: none;
  }
`

const NavItem = styled(props => <Link {...props} />)`
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: #eeeeee;
  margin: 20px 15px 0 0;
  padding-right: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  line-height: 80%;
  &:nth-child(4) {
    border-right: none;
  }
`

const DesktopNav = () => (
  <NavWrapper>
    <NavItem to="/" activeClassName="active">
      home
    </NavItem>
    <NavItem to="/portfolio" activeClassName="active">
      portfolio
    </NavItem>
    <NavItem to="/about" activeClassName="active">
      about
    </NavItem>
    <NavItem to="/contact" activeClassName="active">
      contact
    </NavItem>
  </NavWrapper>
)

export default DesktopNav
```

but when I use `justify-content` to align the nav none of the links are clickable. I have tried re-building the nav without using Gatsby Link like so:

**Re-built Nav component**

```
const DesktopNav = () => (
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/portfolio">portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
)

export default DesktopNav
```

but still anytime I use `justify-content` to align the nav none of the links are clickable, despite the fact that I can see the href set for each element in the browser console.

[image]

I also found that if I remove `justify-content` but keep `display: flex;` that some of the nav links are clickable but others are not. I'm not sure if this has something to do with `display: flex;` setting the container as a block element or if this is a bug of some sort? I have tried this in both Firefox and Chrome using the latest version of Gatsby with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For this type of issues, a codesandbox would help others to identify the problem quickly. You can clone the gatsby codesandbox & try to recreate your issue here: https://codesandbox.io/s/green-silence-83e2f

Comment: It sounds like something's blocking your nav component though. Try bumping up the nav's z-index to see if that helps; once you identified the blocking element you can also alternatively set its `pointer-event` to none

Comment: Yep that was the issue! I had a container overlapping it but didn't notice. Thanks! If you want to submit this as the answer I'll go ahead and accept it.